# Does ng2-image-viewer support tiff images?

Tags: angular, tiff, image-viewer

I am using Angular cli 8.3, and ng2-image-viewer to load a tiff image (base64), but ng2-image-viewer is unable to load the tiff image.
Does ng2-image-viewer support tiff image?

Link to ng2-image-viewer.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-image-viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified and issue is not with Viewer, if u using Chrome, tiff wont be opening as Chrome doesnt support tiff....TRY IE and I am able to display TIFF by using this ng2-viewer...hope this helps others as well...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I am also trying that to load tiff files, but u can try with sample jpg, png files ...if those are getting loaded and tiff files dont, then u have ur answer